# How to click on this link to the next page?

Tags: node.js, button, click, nightmare

Here is everything involving the link:

```
<a class="selected" data-images="{&quot;detail_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/148393/ma/hBwFmRXhVKI.jpg&quot;,&quot;zoomed_url&quot;:&quot;//assets.supremenewyork.com/148393/zo/hBwFmRXhVKI.jpg&quot;}" data-style-name="Black" data-style-id="19033" data-sold-out="false" data-description="null" href="/shop/bags/lkav6jh17/xfdbgpiea" data-no-tubolink="data-no-tubolink"><img width="32" height="32" src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148393/sw/hBwFmRXhVKI.jpg" alt="Hbwfmrxhvki"></a>
```

I use nightmare with node coded in atom and would like to click on the black bookbag from the url: http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/bags/lkav6jh17/p9ylgt8vm
using the "data-style-name="Black" found in the elements.

I've tried:

```
.click("data-style-name ='Black'")
```

which gave me the error:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'data-style-name ='Black'' is not a valid selector.
```

Not sure what to do to click but any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

to click what I wanted I did:

```
.click('a[data-style-name="Tan"]')
```

It was an attribute so i needed to specify that.